Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery with STRING_AGG
I am trying to query information from 2 tables. The PrimaryTable I simply want to return all columns from all rows in that table. The SupportTable I want to just get all of the ID's from that table that are associated with a row in the PrimaryTable and return that as a comma separated string. Note: the SupportTable might have zero or many rows that are associated with a row in the PrimaryTable.
Here's the query I tried that is throwing the error.
SELECT
    PrimaryTable.*,
    STRING_AGG(
        (
            SELECT
                SupportTable.Id
            FROM
                SupportTable
            WHERE
                SupportTable.AssociatedPrimaryTableId = PrimaryTable.Id
        ),
    ',') AS AssociatedSupportTableIds
FROM
    PrimaryTable;

I've found other SO posts that address the error message I'm seeing, but none of those solutions use STRING_AGG() and they all seem to do GROUP BY in their primary table which I don't want to do.

Consider moving your string_agg() into a CROSS APPLY.

@JohnCappelletti beat me to it!

The function needs to put inside the subquery.

I've never used a CROSS APPLY, I'll look it up, thanks!

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).


they all seem to do GROUP BY in their primary table which I don't want to do.

Too bad. You will need GROUP BY for this, but maybe not the way you expect. Try building the column like this:
SELECT
    PrimaryTable.*,
    (
        SELECT
            STRING_AGG(SupportTable.Id, ',')
        FROM
            SupportTable
        WHERE
            SupportTable.AssociatedPrimaryTableId = PrimaryTable.Id
        GROUP BY AssociatedPrimaryTableId 
    )
    AS AssociatedSupportTableIds
FROM
    PrimaryTable;


There is no need for the GROUP BY AssociatedPrimaryTableId - it is pointless with an equality on AssociatedPrimaryTableId and STRING_AGG works fine as a scalar aggregate

this worked for me. And like @MartinSmith said I didn't need the GROUB BY. I'll mark this as the answer once SO lets me here in a minute.

@MartinSmith In the event of transforming this into a CROSS APPLY you will get an inner-join effect with a vector aggregate, as opposed to a left-join effect with a scalar aggregate
